# jQuery load with variable instead of element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, external

i've got a slight jQuery problem.
What i want is to load a particular area of an external html doc into a div,
instead it loads the whole document, not the specified area.

This is the trigger:

```
$('a').click(function(){ // my link to trigger the load
    var pid = $(this).attr('href'); //the pid is the links href
    getproject(pid); //trigger the load function, pass variable
});
```

This is the triggered function:

```
function getproject(pid) {
    $('#container').load('data.html', pid);
}
```

So when i click my link, it should load the element with the id (#) specified by the link into my container, but it loads the whole data... i cant seem to find a solution to this.

The Link looks like this (cant use exact markup here):
a href="#elementtoload"

The data document looks like this:
div id="elementtoload"
div id="..."

and loads of more elements with content, which should be loaded by id from the links href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for $ load, you should be able to do this:

```
function getproject(pid) {
   $('#container').load('data.html #' + pid);
}
```

Comment: .load('data.html #' + pid);
works, got damn it works! Thanks you so much!

Comment: @Michael: That does not really make sense... that means you must have the `#` duplicated in your div's ID.

Comment: ... unless `a href="#elementtoload"` was also a typo, and it doesn't include the hash in the actual markup.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Second section, Loading Page Fragments.  For us to say exactly how this is relevant, you'd need to provide an example of the triggering link, and ideally the document you're loading.

Comment: I know, this is exactly what im trying to accomplish, just with a more dynamic variable

Comment: @Michael Could you provide an example of a link, and the data being loaded?  that should help to clear this up.

Comment: @Michael That might be your problem then.  `div id="#elementtoload"` should read `div id="elementtoload"`.  You don't need a hash in an ID attribute.  In fact, that'll break it :P

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation:

```
.load('data.html ' + pid);
```

Regarding your update:

`<div id="#elementtoload">` should be `<div id="elementtoload">`

Comment: Sorry, it does the exact same for me, loads the whole doc

Comment: @Michael: Does the element with this ID exist in the document? Is it really only the ID or does `pid` contain other text as well?

Comment: It does exist, yes. There are multiple id's in the document, and i want to load one specific id by link. the pid contains the href (#example), i echoed it via alert, it gets passed nicely and should work.

Comment: @Michael: These are the two only problems I could think of why it does not work. String concatenation should work.

Comment: @Michael: The `#` should not be in the div's ID. Remove it and try again with string concatenation, it will work then ;)

Comment: @Michael: Mmmh. Then we cannot say anything anymore... you have to provide a demo or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your actual intent is but it seems to me that you are going to alot of trouble to get the *pid* but then not using it in your load routine. I'm guessing the code should look more like this:

```
function getproject(pid) {
    $(pid).hide().load('data.html');
}
```

Comment: the pid is my links href attribute, why would i want to load my data into that? ;)

Comment: Who knows. Your passing that *pid* as the second argument into a function that expects a callback - and you didn't post whats in your data.html. You might want to clarify in your original question.

Comment: Updated my post, i thought this was the only way to post variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something similar and after some hours (...) michael came finally with something that works :) this did the trick for me, the `#` should be in the url string, like this:

```
$('#div1').load('data.html #' + x);
```